# How can I open a html file, after a php file is run?

Tags: php, html

I am a complete beginner in web development in regards to php. Right not I am using:

```
    <form action="phpfile.php">
    <input type="submit" value="click on me!">
    </form>
```

To open up my php file, which is a simple echo "hello world!" (for testing purposes) The php file that I would use would be this sendmail file

```
    <?php
    $to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Mailer Test';
    $message = 'This is a test, Thanks Person';
    $headers = "From: your@email-address.com\r\n";
    ?>
```

How can, after this is run, a html file would open as soon as the file is done loading? Like a "You have completed the task" page essentially (Also I'm using Xampp which has inbuilt sendmail, so the file does work. Once again temporary before I move onto a webserver)

Thanks!!

Comment: You could redirect to a differtent page after the functions with PHP `header` function, see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: At the bottom of your php file `echo "You have completed the task";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

`header('Location: http://localhost/yourHtmlFile.html');`

but make sure your php didn't output anything before it

**update**

another workaround is to use `include ('yourHtmlFile.html');`

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

PHP can answer code written in HTML back to the browser using echo:

```
<?php
//do some code
$name="superuser";
echo "Hi ".$name;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the answer.